# jQuery: anime.js to multiple same targets

Tags: jquery

```
$(".ml3").spanLetters();

$('.ml3').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {if (isInView) {

    var $this = $(this);  

    anime.timeline({loop: false}).add({
        targets: '.ml3 .letter',
        opacity: [0,1],
        easing: "easeInOutQuad",
        duration: 550,
        delay: function(el, i) {
            return 80 * (i+1)
        }
    });

}});
```

How can I change this so that the animation only fires for the current element in view, not all .ml3 classes on the page? So it uses only 'this' element in view?

Comment: https://animejs.com/documentation/ looks like the targets needs to be a selector, and can't be the element itself.  So if that's true, you could potentially find the index of the `this` in the `$('.ml3')` and then construct a selector using `:nth-child(#)`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  The goal being to try to construct the selector that would target the specific element that the view happened upon.

```js
var $allML3 = $('.ml3').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
  if (isInView) {
    var index = $allML3.index(event.target);
    var specificTargetSelector = `.ml3:nth-child(${index + 1}) .letter`
  
    anime.timeline({
      loop: false
    }).add({
      targets: specificTargetSelector,
      opacity: [0, 1],
      easing: "easeInOutQuad",
      duration: 550,
      delay: function(el, i) {
        return 80 * (i + 1)
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The `index + 1` is due to `:nth-child()` starting at 1 rather than 0.

Comment: Can't get this to work. Im trying to target parent elements but without any luck either here

Comment: @niksos your selector is `h1 span`, but there are no span elements in your h1s